# Функция дублирования текста

Tags: python

Функция должна возвращать что-то вроде этого:

```
спам (1); # Bulochka
спам (3); # bulochkabulochkabulochka
```

А как её написать?

Comment: А где функция и что она возвращает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def spam(number):
     return "bulochka"*number
```

Вызов — `spam(3)`

Comment: Разве все? def spam(number):
    '''Function should return something like this:
    spam(1);#bulochka
    spam(3);#bulochkabulochkabulochka
    But it is broken. Fix it please!
    '''
    return ['bulochka' for i in range(number+1)]

Comment: Это то что мне надо сделать

Comment: Я не понимаю мне надо написать что при вводе чисала допустим 3 должо возвращать 3 слова без пробелов

Comment: @Artem, если у вас есть уточнения вопроса, добавьте их в сам вопрос.

Comment: @Artem исправил ответ. Это то что вам нужно?

Comment: Нет! Если не сложно что надо написать внутри функции она должна возвращять количество слов соответствовать числу

Comment: Спасибо очени помогло

Comment: @Artem проверьте, именно это она и возвращает.

Comment: Спасибо помогло))